# transition matrix of random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Is asking about transition matrix in one dimensional random walk $X_n=U_0+U_1+...+U_n$ with $P(U_k=1)=p$, $P(U_k=-1)=1-p$ make sense?

If $n$ is even like $88$ then for example $p_{10,11}=P(X_n=11|X_{n-1}=10)$ is $0$ or is undefined? $X_{88}$ can't equal $11$ but $X_{87}$ couln't equal to $10$ in the first place.

If it make sense then this matrix has to be dependent on $n$ right? (be not homogeneous?)

Answer (score 0):

The Markov chain is still time homogeneous - the transition matrix is still bi-diagonal.

The Markov chain cannot reach certain state in the odd / even steps does not mean it is not homogeneous. Some Markov chain can be periodic too.

Note the transition matrix stores the values of the transition probabilities $\Pr\{X_{k+1} = j | X_k = i\}$

By definition,

$$ \Pr\{X_1 = 1|X_0 = 0\} = p, \Pr\{X_1 = -1|X_0 = 0\} = 1 - p, 
\Pr\{X_1 = 0|X_0 = 0\} = 0$$

But these transition probabilities are different from marginal probabilities - i.e. we cannot simply say $\Pr\{X_1 = 0\} = 0$ without mentioning the initial distribution of $X_0$.

Also, these transition probabilities does not conditional on the value of $X_0$. i.e.

$$ \Pr\{X_3 = 0|X_0 = 0\} = 0 \neq p = \Pr\{X_3 = 0|X_2 = -1\} $$

You maybe still thinking of the probabilities like
$$ \Pr\{X_3 = 0|X_2 = -1, X_0 = 0\} $$

This is true that this is ill defined because the event $X_2 = -1, X_0 = 0$ has a probability of $0$. But this quantity is not the same as the transition probability - the transition matrix just store information about something like $\Pr\{X_{k+1} = 0|X_k = -1\} $ without the information of the initial distribution $X_0$.

Comment: yeah but depending of parity of $n$ different entries will be not zero (if we assume that probability $p_{i,j}$ is $0$ when for example $n$ is odd and $j$ is odd) so for different $n$ we will have different matrices

Comment: Still the same matrix - even if you take the $n$-th power, you get the $n$-step transition matrix, the probability is still depending on the initial distribution. You may write one, say $3$ states only transition matrix and you should understand the mechanism after some simple calcuation.

Comment: okay matrix is the same because it is infinite in both directions, so it happen to not matter but then the convention is that for example $P(X_4=1|X_3=0)=0$ even though $P(X_3=0)=0$ if we start random walk at 0 (X_0=1), but that contradict definition of conditional probability

Comment: nooo, now I see that it is not the same, for bigger n more entries are non zero, for example for n=100 every p_{i,j} is 0 for i or j bigger than 100